# Compare String without Case Sensitivity Check

Tags: php

I am trying to compare my string like below.

```
$recieved = "SR1";
if ($recieved == "SR1" || $recieved == "SR2"|| $recieved == "SR3"|| $recieved == "SR4"){
    echo "matching";
}
else{
    echo "not matching";
}
```

This is working fine but I want to ignore case sensitivity checking like below

```
sr1
Sr1
sR1
```

I don't have idea how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you could achieve that by using strtoupper function, also, I would suggest to use in_array like so:

```
$recieved = "SR1";
if (in_array(strtoupper($recieved), ['SR1', 'SR2', 'SR3', 'SR4'])) {
    echo "matching";
} else {
    echo "not matching";
}
```

I hope that works well for you.

Comment: `mb_strtoupper` would be safer in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `preg_match` in case insensitive mode:

```
$received = "sR1";
if (preg_match("/sr1/i", $received, $matches)) {
    echo "match";
}
```

This approach would also be a good starting point if you might have the need to match `sR1`, `SR1`, etc., as it appears inside a larger string.  In that case, we could try searching for `\bsr1\b` using `preg_match` in case insensitive mode.

Comment: Regex is a little bit of overkill for such a simple task.And I am not sure that this is entirely correct solution. https://ideone.com/Sq7JIF

Comment: You are looking at edge cases far away from the OP's problem statement.

Comment: How is it an edge case?

Comment: If the use case is `SR` and any number I think a regex is probably a better approach. Don't need to define every possible integer. Might want to add anchors though.